# Does EthereumJ (Java implementation of Ethereum) support JSON RPC API?

Tags: json-rpc, ethereumj, java

Looking at their github repository and searching through the source code, I could not find JSON RPC API, except the one for Whisper. Perhaps I did not look hard enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently EthereumJ has no JSON-RPC support, however we are planning to implement this in a nearest future as a separate project which also will include Web3 JS console

Answer (score 4):

02/04/2016 I had a better look and no, there is no JSON-RPC API service.

07/04/2016 - The new changes to be merged that was referred to by @Oscar Guindzberg at https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/pull/352/files has a JSON RPC API with jetty for the HTTP handling and jsonrpc4j for the JSON conversions. Nice.

Answer (score 3):

There is a non-merged pull request you can try
https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/pull/352